# NSString and NSDictionary valueForKey - nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I put a default value into my string if getting data from an empty key/value in a dictionary.

so `[myObject setMyString:[dictionary valueForKey:@"myKey"]];`

So then if I did `NSString *newString = myObject.myString` I would get an `unrecognized selector error`.

So again, I simply need a way to insert a default string if the key value is empty;

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, can you clarify?

Comment: You can't get a nil value from a dictionary.  If nil is returned that means that the key does not exist in the dictionary.  If you want to store a (conceptual) nil value in a dictionary you should use the NSNull object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about this?

```
NSString *value = [dictionary valueForKey:@"myKey"];
if (!value) value = @"defaultValue";
[myObject setMyString:value];
```

Comment: Also possible to do `[myObject setMyString:[dic...Key:@"myKey"] ?: @"defaultValue"];`

Comment: I know this method works, but was looking for more of a one liner

myObject.myString = [dictionary valueForKey@"myKey"] ? [dictionary valueForKey@"myKey"] : @"";

This doesn't seem to work. If there is a value for the key, use the value for the  key else do @""

Comment: One could always create a category for NSArray, something like `objectForKey:(id)key withDefault:(id)defaultObject`.  This would allow a "one liner" operation.

Answer (score 11):

If `dictionary` is a `NSDictionary` you should probably use `objectForKey` as `valueForKey` is used for [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170). It works for `NSDictionary` but may bite you if the key collide with some `NSDictionary` KVC key, e.g. "@allKeys" or "@count".

I think the shortest is probably to do:

```
[dictionary objectForkey:@"myKey"] ?: @"defaultValue"
```

There is one terrible way of abusing the existing dictionary methods to produce a get by key or return a default value if you don't want to use a condition for some reason...

```
[[dictionary objectsForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"myKey"]
             notFoundMarker:@"defaultValue"]
 objectAtIndex:0]
```

You did not hear it from me :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `[NSNull null]` for the general case, and handle it when that is returned.

In your question, you wouldn't get "unrecognised selector"; `newString` would be set to `nil` (as opposed to `[NSNull null]`, so I suspect you might have meant something else - perhaps how to set defaults values for `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this with a simple NSDictionary extension.

NSDictionary+NSDictionaryExtensions.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (NSDictionaryExtensions)

- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey defaultObject: (id) defObj;

@end
```

NSDictionary+NSDictionaryExtensions.m

```
#import "NSDictionary+NSDictionaryExtensions.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (NSDictionaryExtensions)

- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey defaultObject: (id) defObj
{
    id ret = [self objectForKey: aKey];
    if ( ret == nil )
        return defObj;
    else
        return ret;
}

@end
```

I can then access as follows:

```
NSString* str = [dict objectForKey: @"a_key" defaultObject: @"default"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ( myObject == nil ) {
   [myObject setMyString:@""];
}
```

or

```
if ( [dictionary valueForKey:@"myKey"] == nil ) {
    [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"myKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever default value you assigned to your string it will not make `myObject.myString` return "unrecognized selector error" - usually the property `myString` either exists or it does not ('usually' as you can dig into the guts of the Objective-C runtime and play games, but this is rarely (if ever) what you want to do!)

What are you trying to do? If your aim is to throw an exception on `myObject.myString` not being set then you can do that in the property implementation.

For example, `valueForKey;` will return `nil` if there is no value set for a given key, so you can check for that in your property:

```
- (void) setMyString:(NSString *)value
{  myString = value;
}

- (NSString *) myString
{
   if (myString == nil)
      @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"UnrecognizedSelector" reason:@"No value set for myString" userInfo:nil];
   return myString;
}
```

Notes:

1. code typed at terminal, may contain typos
2. code assumes garbage collection/ARC on, if not you need to add appropriate retain/copy/release

But do you really want to throw an exception? You would normally only do so if the string *should* be set and not being so is an *exceptional* condition - you don't throw for default values.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Paul Lynch you must check for [NSNull null] apart from nil. It is also advisable to check for the data type you are looking for:

```
- (id) objectForKey: (id) key withDefault: (id) defaultValue
{
    id value = self[key];

    if (value == nil || [value isEqual: [NSNull null]] || ![defaultValue isKindOfClass: [value class]])
    {
        value = defaultValue;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check for nil values as below for different types:

```
extension NSDictionary {

func convertToString() -> String {
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) as NSData!

    if jsonData  == nil{
        return "{}"
    }else {
        return String(data: jsonData as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_Int(aKey: String) -> Int {

    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return Int()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return Int()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return Int()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return Int()
    }
    else if(aValue.isKind(of: NSString.self)){
        return Int((aValue as! NSString).intValue)
    }
    else {

        if aValue is Int {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! Int
        }
        else{
            return Int()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_CGFloat(aKey: String) -> CGFloat {

    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return CGFloat()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return CGFloat()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return CGFloat()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return CGFloat()
    }
    else {

        if aValue is CGFloat {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! CGFloat
        }
        else{
            return CGFloat()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_String(aKey: String) -> String {

    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return String()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return String()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return String()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return String()
    }
    else if(aValue.isKind(of: NSNumber.self)){
        return String(format:"%f", (aValue as! NSNumber).doubleValue)
    }
    else {

        if aValue is String {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! String
        }
        else{
            return String()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_StringInt(aKey: String) -> String {

    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return String()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return String()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return String()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return String()
    }
    else if(aValue.isKind(of: NSNumber.self)){
        return String(format:"%d", (aValue as! NSNumber).int64Value)


    }
    else {

        if aValue is String {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! String
        }
        else{
            return String()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_Bool(aKey: String) -> Bool {
    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return Bool()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return Bool()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return Bool()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return Bool()
    }
    else {

        if aValue is Bool {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! Bool
        }
        else{
            return Bool()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_NSArray(aKey: String) -> NSArray {
    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return NSArray()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return NSArray()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return NSArray()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return NSArray()
    }
    else {
        if aValue is NSArray {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! NSArray
        }
        else{
            return NSArray()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_NSMutableArray(aKey: String) -> NSMutableArray {
    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return NSMutableArray()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return NSMutableArray()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return NSMutableArray()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return NSMutableArray()
    }
    else {

        if aValue is NSMutableArray {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! NSMutableArray
        }
        else{
            return NSMutableArray()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_NSDictionary(aKey: String) -> NSDictionary {
    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return NSDictionary()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return NSDictionary()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return NSDictionary()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return NSDictionary()
    }
    else {

        if aValue is NSDictionary {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! NSDictionary
        }
        else{
            return NSDictionary()
        }
    }
}

func object_forKeyWithValidationForClass_NSMutableDictionary(aKey: String) -> NSMutableDictionary {
    // CHECK FOR EMPTY
    if(self.allKeys.count == 0) {
        return NSMutableDictionary()
    }

    // CHECK IF KEY EXIST
    if let val = self.object(forKey: aKey) {
        if((val as AnyObject).isEqual(NSNull())) {
            return NSMutableDictionary()
        }
    } else {
        // KEY NOT FOUND
        return NSMutableDictionary()
    }

    // CHECK FOR NIL VALUE
    let aValue : AnyObject = self.object(forKey: aKey)! as AnyObject
    if aValue.isEqual(NSNull()) {
        return NSMutableDictionary()
    }
    else {
        if aValue is NSMutableDictionary {
            return self.object(forKey: aKey) as! NSMutableDictionary
        }
        else{
            return NSMutableDictionary()
        }
    }
}
```

}